# Change texture transparency at runtime on MonoGame

Tags: transparency, textures, monogame

I am very new with MonoGame library.
I load a texture from .xnb file

```
_background = content.Load<Texture2D>(_backgroundKey);
```

and then i want to change it transparancy(alpha) at the runtime.

Oh i found how to do it myself

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRect, Color.White * 0.5f, .......);
```

This line of code will draw the texture at half transparency.

Comment: Oh i found an answer myselft, i need to user something like this:

Comment: Please post your answer to yourself as an answer, then mark it as accepted rather than editing your initial post.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the opacity of a texture by using a (semi-)transparent color in the draw call:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Color(Color.Pink, 0.5f);
```

The values range from 0 (completely transparent) to 1 (completely opaque). `Color` has a [lot of different constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color.color%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx), so you can also pass a byte (0-255) instead of a float, which will result in the same thing.